# TIME Input Field in Rails Form

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, timepicker

I've got a form for where one of the inputs is selecting a TIME data type when updating a record. I'm using Simple Form and Jquery Timepicker.

The record saves correctly in the database but when the record reloads it displays in the view to the user as 8PM or 20:00 hrs.

How can I get the field to correctly show the time that is in the database vs. this default 8PM?

**The View**

```
<%= f.input :mondayopen, :as => :string, :label => 'Opens at', :input_html => { :class => 'mondayo' } %>
```

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `storeimage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `storename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `storemessage` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `mondayopen` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=114 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Controller**

```
  def update
    @store = Store.find(current_user.store.id)
    if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
      flash[:success] = "Store has been updated"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**Here is how the user sees it**
[image]

**Here is what is in the database**
[image]

Comment: you mean whatever time you selected, in database it is appearing as 8 pm??

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: I've posted my code. Yes, whatever time I've selected in the database is appearing as 8PM

Comment: Does your script passes a simple string to the mondayopen column? If it is, this column should be a simple t.string in your DB, not a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the Time column in the database to a string as suggested by @Cadence96. That worked.